# CSS Animations are not smooth on Chrome (iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with CSS animations on Chrome browser, on iOS device.
Animations are snapping into place and are not smooth.
On Safari, Firefox or desktop Chrome everything works great.

Here is a simple example which is laggy on iOS version of Chrome:

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transition: 2s;
}

.test:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uLgd8s7j/2/)

Is there any way to make such animations more smooth?

Comment: not sure if this will make it any smoother but you should try adding more browser support.
`-o-transform, -moz-transform, -ms-transform, -webkit-transform`
the webkit transform may be used by chrome, but cannot confirm.

Comment: it works fine on my device, it doesnt seem reproducible, have you tested on other devices?

Comment: furthermore what iphone are you using to test. it is possible it is just slow after hearing @ImmortalDude's response.

Comment: @Shawn Pacarar Im using IphoneXS so there is no problem with hardware for sure.

Comment: @Immortal Dude are you sure you tested this on ios on chrome?

Comment: Just tested on iPhone 8 Plus running iOS 12.2 with Chrome.  Smooth as silk.  Not laggy at all.

Comment: @Knight yes, iPhone 5s, no problems, try using a different browser, it might bechrome not playing nice

Comment: It looks like Private Tab on my Chrome, makes animations slow and choppy. Thanks a lot guys for your help :)

Comment: How are you using `:hover` on a mobile device?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I open an Incognito tab in Chrome on my iOS device, it does not affect the animation at all (still smooth / non-laggy)

Comment: @zero298 taping on device works like hover on desktop.

Comment: @cale_b so it looks like my Chrome acts wierd. Thank You for help :)

Comment: I had the same problem on iphone 8, I updated the chrome browser and now it solve the animation problems

Answer (score 6):

My animations were choppy in chrome (like 2 frames per second). Maybe because traumatic experiences with bug fixing in the past has trained me to expect that its never this easy - but it took me a few minutes before I decided to restart Chrome on my iPhone.

I had over 10 tabs open. Once I closed them and restarted Chrome the animation was all good.

Hopefully this helps someone to feel slightly less silly.

Comment: Even without closing any tabs, simply closing and reopening Chrome iOS works. Looks like a memory leak and it is still there in the current latest stable version 106.0

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is an open bug on Chrome iOS just to follow up on this one? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The will-change CSS property hints to browsers how an element is expected to change.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

```css
.test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transition: 2s;
}

.test:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```